# angular 2 | can't get child directives with @ContentChildren

Tags: asynchronous, angular, directive, children

I'm trying to get nested directives from a parent directive, but @ContentChildren not being populated. basically I'm building a lazy-load on images, each image is a nested directive from a parent directive

---

### **example:**

**parent.directive.ts**:

```
import ...

@Directive({
    'selector': 'parentSelector'
})
export class ParentDirective implements onInit, AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(ChildDirective) private items: QueryList<ChildDirective>;

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        console.log(this.items, this.items.toArray()); // <---

        // call a child directive method...
        this.items.forEach((item: ChildDirective) => {
            item.makeSomething();
        });
    }
}
```

here, `this.items` wasn't populated

**child.directive.ts**:

```
import ...

@Directive({
    selector: 'childSelector'
})
export class ChildDirective {
    makeSomething(): void {
        console.log('called from ParentDirective');
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import ...

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<div>
        <some-component parentSelector [items]="itemsData"></some-component>
    </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    // NOTE: "itemsData" is loaded asynchronously from a service
    ...
}
```

property **"itemsData"** is loaded asynchronously from a service

**some-component.component.html**

```
<!-- 'items' was obtained from AppComponent @Input('items')
     see also: 'itemsData' on AppComponent
-->

<div *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img childSelector src="image.src">
</div>
```

problem is on 'some-component' cycle, since the data is loaded asynchronously, @ContentChildren is empty.

NOTE: all images are displayed on **some-component**

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug (fixed in 2.0.1) that `@ContentChildren()` didn't search descendants by default. You can work around with setting it explicitly

```
@ContentChildren(ChildDirective, {descendants: true})
```

In 2.0.1 `true` is the default value.

Comment: This change only affected `@ContentChild()`. `@ContentChildren()` still requires setting `descendants` to `true`.